# Access to a constant value with a variable name in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-developer-api

First of all, I don't know if there is a way to achieve what I want to, but I don't lose nothing asking for.

SO, I have an object with some constant values, let's say:

```
object Properties {
    const val A1 = 1
    const val A2 = 2
    const val A3 = 3
    ....
}
```

The user in the app, will choose one of these options: A1, A2,A3,..., An, and I'm saving the user's option in the variable

```
val userOption
```

Now, I want to access which value is userOption (1,2,3,...,n) referring to the object Properties, something like this:

```
val index = Properties.$userOption
```

Obviously, this is wrong, but I wanted to know if it exists something similar to access a constant value with another variable name.what So basically, I have the value in another variable name that is not in the class and is called "userOption".

For example,the user has many options in a spinner: A1, A2, ..., An

```
var userOption: String = null
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {
        // retrieve the selected item
        userOption = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
    }

private fun getIndexUserOption(){
    val indexUser = Properties.$userOption // this is wrong!
}
```

Thank you all!

PS. I do not want to use a dictionary in this class because it has to work in differents classes.

Comment: You may want to expand your explanation and code examples. I, for one, am not clear on what you're asking or trying to achieve.

Comment: @dominicoder I added an example! thank you

Comment: What or where is `userOption` though? Are you looking for [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)?

Comment: userOption is the selected item of a spinner

Comment: No, that's the value. What is the _variable_? `val userOption` - what is that? Where does that live? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand your question but I would use enums like in the playground example below:

```
enum class Props {
    A1,
    A2,
    A3
}

fun main() {
    var userChoice: Props = Props.A2
    val index = userChoice.ordinal
    val literal = Props.values()[index]
    print(index)
    print(literal)
}
```

The only difference is that the values start at 0. So A1 is 0, A2 is 1 and A3 is 2.
Printing the index will show 1. And printing the literal will show A2.

You can do more fancy stuff using enums but I think it's a better start than other approaches.

Comment: Yeah this is probably your best option, since an enum is *enumerated* so each constant has a specific "index" you can refer to it by. So you can easily display all the enum `values()` in a spinner or list, and use the index of the chosen option to fetch the associated constant. And they play nice with serialisation too!

Comment: not exactly what I wanted because here you are accessing the value with the variable name "A2" and in my case I have the value in another variable name that is not in the enum class